# Terraform setproduct with inner loop

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a CloudWatch alarm that will cycle through instances defined in data.tf and for each on of these to cycle through the volume id's

**data.tf**

```
data "aws_instances" "instance_cloudwatch" {

  instance_tags = {
    Type        = var.type
  }
}
data "aws_ebs_volumes" "cw_volumes" {
   tags = {
     Name = var.name
   }
  }
data "aws_ebs_volume" "cw_volume" {
  for_each    = toset(data.aws_ebs_volumes.cw_volumes.ids)
  filter {
    name      = "volume-id"
    values    = [each.value]
  }
}
```

In the resource I created

```
locals {
   vol_map = {
     for pair in setproduct(data.aws_instances.instance_cloudwatch.ids,data.aws_ebs_volume.cw_volume.*.id) : "${pair[0]}-${pair[1]}" => {
        id = pair[0]
        vol = pair[1]
    }
  }    
}
```

And then I try to use these pairs in the alarm dimensions

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "some_alarm" {
  for_each                  = local.vol_map
...
      dimensions = {
        InstanceId   = each.value.id
        VolumeId     = each.value.vol
      }
```

When I run terraform apply I get this error

*Error: Unsupported attribute*

*for pair in setproduct(data.aws_instances.instance_cloudwatch.ids,data.aws_ebs_volume.cw_volume.*.id) : "${pair[0]}-${pair[1]}" => {*

*This object does not have an attribute named "id"* I tried volume_id and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't use the `.*.` syntax (in `data.aws_instances.instance_cloudwatch.ids,data.aws_ebs_volume.cw_volume.*.id`) on a resource that you created with `for_each`. The `.*.` syntax only works when you use `count`. This is because it only works with arrays/lists, and `for_each` creates a map.

Try `values(data.aws_instances.instance_cloudwatch.ids,data.aws_ebs_volume.cw_volume).*.id`. This will get the `data.aws_ebs_volume.cw_volume` values as a list instead of a map, so you can then use `.*.` on them.